# Qt Application not running

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am trying to run a simple "Hello, world" console application but I am experiencing some errors when compiling that I am not familiar with. I have done a bit of research into similar problems with Qt but I haven't been able to find a solution. The closest solution I have come across was to change my Patch Command setting under:

```
Preferences -> Environment -> System -> Patch Command
```

to

```
usr/bin/xterm -e
```

However, when I try to do this it goes red indicating that I do not have this file.

Environment Preferences Window

[image]

The following image is a screenshot of what is displayed in the terminal window when attempting to compile my project.

Console Application Output

[image]

Any help on this problem would be much apprectiated! It is very frustrating having something like this hold me back!

Answer (score 1):

Don't run your project in a terminal unless you actually select a working terminal, and that's all. The patch command is irrelevant in this anyway - it's not the terminal, but the **patch** command -- used to patch source code. You don't need it unless you explicitly use code patching. Go to Projects (Ctrl-5), click on the active Run configuration for your project, uncheck "Run in terminal", done.